# Nested JSON Object Parsing in android using volley

Tags: java, android, json

I need your help in parsing nested JSON Object.

Attached the JSON data:

```
{
  "31": {
    "basic": {
      "node_id": "31",
      "title": "test",
      "alias": "test",
      "description": "test",
      "site_id": "151336557",
      "node_type": "7",
      "privacy": "7",
      "deleted": "0",
      "status": "1",
      "created_date": "1379169518",
      "updated_date": "1379169518",
      "created_by": "140513626519686828",
      "updated_by": null,
      "readable_date": "14th Sep, 2013"
    },
    "meta": {
      "forum_id": "61"
    },
    "comments": {
      "count": 1
    },
    "likes": {
      "count": 0
    },
    "tags": [],
    "node_id": "31"
  },
  "32": {
    "basic": {
      "node_id": "32",
      "title": "testing discussion",
      "alias": "testing-discussion",
      "description": "testing",
      "site_id": "151336557",
      "node_type": "7",
      "privacy": "7",
      "deleted": "0",
      "status": "1",
      "created_date": "1379493816",
      "updated_date": "1379493816",
      "created_by": "140513795022034166",
      "updated_by": null,
      "readable_date": "18th Sep, 2013"
    },
    "meta": {
      "forum_id": "65"
    },
    "comments": {
      "count": 1
    },
    "likes": {
      "count": 0
    },
    "tags": [],
    "node_id": "32"
  }
}
```

Attaching the Java Code:

```
private void makeJsonObjectRequest() {
     showpDialog();

     JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,            urlJsonObj, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

         @Override
         public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
             Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

             JSONObject phone = response.getJSONObject("31").getJSONObject("basic");
             String name = phone.getString("title");
             String email = phone.getString("description");
             JSONObject comments = response.getJSONObject("31").getJSONObject("comments");
             String home = comments.getString("count");
             JSONObject like = response.getJSONObject("31").getJSONObject("likes");
             String mobile = like.getString("count");

             jsonResponse = "";
             jsonResponse += "Name: " + name + "\n\n";
             jsonResponse += "Email: " + email + "\n\n";
             jsonResponse += "Home: " + home + "\n\n";
             jsonResponse += "Mobile: " + mobile + "\n\n\n";

             txtResponse.setText(jsonResponse);
```

I need to retrieve all the objects but here i am retrieving only one object(I meant all `node_id`s). I need your suggestions .
Thanks.

Comment: Use this site http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/, It helps you in converting from Json to Object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the entry with key `"31"` (`response.getJSONObject("31")`), however, you should iterate all keys:

```
 JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET, urlJsonObj, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
     @Override
     public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
         for (String key : response.keySet()) {
             JSONObject entry = response.getJSONObject(key);
             Log.d(TAG, entry.toString());

             JSONObject phone = entry.getJSONObject("basic");
             String name = phone.getString("title");
             String email = phone.getString("description");
             JSONObject comments = entry.getJSONObject("comments");
             String home = comments.getString("count");
             JSONObject like = entry.getJSONObject("likes");
             String mobile = like.getString("count");

             jsonResponse = "";
             jsonResponse += "Name: " + name + "\n\n";
             jsonResponse += "Email: " + email + "\n\n";
             jsonResponse += "Home: " + home + "\n\n";
             jsonResponse += "Mobile: " + mobile + "\n\n\n";

             txtResponse.setText(txtResponse.getText() + "\n\n" + jsonResponse); //get the old text and add it to it
         }
     } 
}
```

EDIT: you state you want only the `node_id`'s? That's possible too:

```
 JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET, urlJsonObj, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
     @Override
     public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
         List<String> nodeIds = new ArrayList<String>();
         for (String key : response.keySet()) {
             JSONObject entry = response.getJSONObject(key);
             nodeIds.add(enty.getJSONObject("basic").getString("node_id"));
         }
         txtResponse.setText(ListUtils.toString(nodeIds)); //from apaches commons library
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply . I tried your code but I get this error "Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable" for response.keys()." can u suggest?

Comment: @srikanth Make `keys()` `keySet()`

Comment: @gogu from what package do you import JSONObject?

Answer (score 0):

on this part

```
response.getJSONObject("31")
```

you need to change `31` for a variable and call this to every field of your object